# Pass list as one of function's arguments

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I wanted to store username&password from login form in session, for future use in REST requests:

```
request.session['credentials'] = (request.POST['username'],request.POST['password'])
```

Than, using python requests module (and my custom wrapper), I wanted to pass it as auth headers for remote connection request:

```
devices = client['devices/'].get(auth=request.session['credentials'])
```

but I'm getting error:

> 'list' object is not callable

This works like a charm when instead of `request.session['credentials']` I will pass something like: `('admin','admin')`

How can I pass such argument?

Comment: What is the *full* traceback of the exception?

Comment: And when you print request.session['credentials'] what do you get?

Comment: When I print request.session['credentials'] I get:
[u'admin', u'admin']

Comment: Django can handle all this for you, why aren't you using django's built in session storage? See here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you get a list, but passing a tuple works. Try

```
tuple(request.session['credentials'])
```